# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.play.findnearplace.Md$Holder

Tags: android, listview

just i create on listview using Baseadapter but i suddenly getting error like
"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.play.findnearplace.Md$Holder"  Problem is in getView() else condition holder get Integer vlue like 0.

```
public class Md extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    public List<FD> itemsData;
    public List<FD> orig;
    OnClickListener onclick;
    Context context;
    int id;

    public Md(List<FD> itemsData, OnClickListener onclick, int id,MainActivity main) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
        this.onclick = onclick;
        this.id = id;
        this.context=main;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsData.size();
    }

    @Override

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    private class Holder
    {
        public ImageView ui;
        public TextView tt;

        public RelativeLayout rl_main_child;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder;  
        Log.i("Second", "1");
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null)
        {

            Log.i("Second", "2");
        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_child, parent,false);
        holder = new Holder();
        Log.i("Second", "3");
        holder.ui = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgunit);
        holder.tt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        Log.i("Second", ""+holder);
        }else
        {
            Log.i("Second", ""+convertView.getTag());
            holder=(Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.i("Second", "5");
        FD m=itemsData.get(position);
        holder.rl_main_child=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main_child);
        holder.rl_main_child.setTag(position);
         holder.tt.setText(m.gettitle());
        holder.rl_main_child.setOnClickListener(onclick);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final List<FD> results = new ArrayList<FD>();
                if (orig == null)
                    orig = itemsData;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                        for (final FD g : orig) {
                            if (g.gettitle().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 itemsData = (ArrayList<FD>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Error.....

```
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417): Process: com.play.findnearplace, PID: 14417
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.play.findnearplace.Md$Holder
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at com.play.findnearplace.Md.getView(Md.java:80)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2303)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
05-18 23:43:20.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14417):
```

My Log.....

```
05-19 00:28:14.646: I/Second(17516): 1
05-19 00:28:14.646: I/Second(17516): 2
05-19 00:28:14.655: I/Second(17516): 3
05-19 00:28:14.655: I/Second(17516): com.play.findnearplace.Md$Holder@42544570
05-19 00:28:14.655: I/Second(17516): 5
05-19 00:28:14.660: I/Second(17516): 1
05-19 00:28:14.660: I/Second(17516): 0
```

main_child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main_child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:background="@color/white" >

            <com.play.findnearplace.T
                android:id="@+id/txttitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgunit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What unclear is in Exception you are getting? Its message is pretty clear. Also you got exact line and file it in your stacktrace, so what is exactly your question?

Comment: that's fun. Can you post main_child.xml?

Comment: i cant fill data in  listview ..i getting above error

Comment: why are you not having `holder.rl_main_child=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main_child);` inside `if(convertView==null)`

Comment: i put holder.rl_main_child=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main_child); in if(convertView==null) but still having same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in those two lines:

```
  holder.rl_main_child=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main_child);
  holder.rl_main_child.setTag(position);
```

in the first one you are assigning the `convertView` to `rl_main_child`, and with the second one you are overriding the tag. Hence the second time `getView` is called you try to cast the tag to `Holder`, but since you overrode it with an integer, `position`, you get a `ClassCastException`. Get rid of  `holder.rl_main_child.setTag(position);`, and it will work

Comment: delete `holder.rl_main_child.setTag(position);` and run it again

Comment: yes you r write ..i just remove  this line holder.rl_main_child.setTag(position); than its work fine ...but i want to also setTag of holder.rl_main_child

Comment: you can't use `rl_main_child` because it contains already your Holder. Use another view. you could use `tt`

Answer (score 0):

The line `FD m=itemsData.get(position);` is causing the problem. 
You are trying to convert int to type FD

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(convertView==null) {
    // your existing code
    holder.rl_main_child=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main_child);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else {
   // your existing code
}

// no need to do below statement, hence commented
//holder.rl_main_child.setTag(position);
holder.tt.setText(m.gettitle());
holder.rl_main_child.setOnClickListener(onclick);
```